# How to run multiple test cases without running before and after class again and again

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, testng

I want to know how run multiple files without running the before class() again and again.

**E.g.:**
Consider i am writing test case for GMail

1. `login.java` : Which contains complete testing of the login page
2. `inbox.java` : Which contains complete testing of the inbox
3. `spam.java` : Which contains complete testing of the spam folder page
4. `label.java` : Which contains complete testing of create/edit/deleting of labels

Now every file contains a before class which has

1. calling the browser
2. input username and password
3. clicking the submit button
   and after class which logs out

Using TestNG when I run, every time it will login, test for the particular file and logs out

It needs to run like this:
It should login, then test the inbox, spam and label then logs out.

Is it the right way to execute? Or is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this-

```
public class GmailContentTesting
{
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseUrl ="http://www.gmail.com";

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup()
    {
        /*System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Browsers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();*/
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @BeforeTest
    public void gmailLogin()
    {
        WebElement EmailTextbox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'Email')]"));
        EmailTextbox.clear();
        EmailTextbox.sendKeys("your email");

        WebElement nextButton =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'next')]"));
        nextButton.click();


        WebElement PasswdTextbox =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'Passwd')]"));
        PasswdTextbox.clear();
        PasswdTextbox.sendKeys("Your Passwd");


        WebElement SigninButton =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'signIn')]")); 
        SigninButton.click();
    }
        @Test(priority=1)
        public void inboxTesting()
        {
                  Write your code for complete testing of the inbox
        }

        @Test(priority=2)
        public void spamTesting()
        {
                  Write your code for complete testing of the spam folder page
        }


        @Test(priority=3)
        public void lableTesting()
        {
                  Write your code for  complete testing of create/edit/deleting of labels
        }

    @AfterTest
        public void Logout()
        {
                  Write your code for  Gmail Logout.
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your code prevents the BeforeTest and AfterTest routines from running before and after each Test routine?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `@BeforeSuite`

You have to group your test classes into a suite in the testng.xml and annotate the setup method in one of your test classes.

This link provides a nice tutorial:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-beforesuite-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

1. Have a static driver inside the test class; static WebDriver driver = null;
2. Create a single `@BeforeClass`, which will initialize the driver to your desired browser, navigate to gmail and login.
3. Have `@Test` annotations for all the 4 cases.
4. Remove/comment out all other tags from those individual classes. Just have them as methods. Then call those methods from inside your `@Test` methods.
5. Finally have a `@AfterClass` to logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your script class ;

```
public class gmailTest extends BaseTest
{
    @Test
    public void loginLogoutTest()
    {
        inboxTest();
        spamTest();
    }

public void inboxTest()
{
    log.info("Executing inboxTest");
            //Your code here
    log.info("loginToApplication has been Successfully Excecuted");
}
public void spamTest()
    {
        log.info("Executing spamTest");
            //Your code here
        log.info("spamTest has been Successfully Excecuted");
    }
```

}

1. Now call it where ever required
2. Here we have only one **@test** so your gmail login will login one time from **@beforetest** and logout once from **@aftertest**.

Hope it help and revert if still more doubts.

Comment: i am using it in my script and working as expected so can try ,it will work and will reduce the code as we can reuse the codes here